# USB communication on GluonHQ for IPhone and Android?

Tags: java, javafx, usb, gluon-mobile

Have GluonHQ support for USB communication when it comes to IPhone and Android?

Or do I need to use a third part library? Like this: https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm

Edit:
The reason why I'm asking is because I need some kind of communication tool between an embedded system and a phone. First I was looking at Bluetooth Charm Down, but according to the docs, I cannot send bytes from it.

Edit2:
The required protocols I'm seeking is USB and Bluetooth BLE.
I'm looking for some way to communicate with other devices over for example USB and BLE in the "Arduino"-way. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/softwareSerial

The basic functionality I'm seeking is:

- Check if bytes are available
- Flush the bytes in the buffert
- Read byte
- Read all bytes
- Write byte
- Write array of bytes
- Close
- Open

Comment: Are you aware that most of these protocols are not allowed on iOS... (regular Bluetooth, USB)?

Comment: @josépreda but isint BLE better than classical bluetooth? Iphone don't have USB protocol?

Comment: If you can use BLE, that could work, it is supported in both Android and iOS. Apple doesn't let you use USB unless you join a very restricted program: http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

Comment: @JoséPereda Is BLE for Android/iOS supported by Gluon too? I mean that I can send bytes to another device. I know that Gluon support some beacons for BLE.

Comment: BLE is supported to an extension. Initially it was implemented for beacons discovery.

Comment: @JoséPereda So there is no idea for me to create a mobile application with Gluon framework if I want to communicate with another embedded device? I'm going to build another project with this framework. Right now I looking for tools and solution before I go any further in typing the keyboard.

Comment: You can add your native implementation of services that are not included yet in Charm Down. See for instance [Go Native](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/go-native). And you could edit your question and post the details of the communication protocol that is required?

Comment: @JoséPereda Native services? You mean that I can run the real Android API from google onto GluonHQ framework?

Comment: Yes, have a look at the sample I linked above, and also to the Charm Down [library](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/default/).

Comment: @JoséPereda Thank you. I will try implement it on my Git project.

Comment: @JoséPereda Hi again! Is it possible to use a java Bluetooth BLE library instead by using Go Native? https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle

Comment: In theory you can use any Android or iOS third party library/framework, Go Native is just a very basic sample that shows how to add and build native libraries for your project.

Comment: @JoséPereda Ok. I think I will give the GoNative a try first. I tried to insert this code as a field `private final static String TAG = AndroidLogService.class.getSimpleName();` but Gluon could not find the `AndroidLogService` class. Is it something else I have I have forgot? I have access to Gluon Charm library.

Comment: Do as Go Native. Android code only can be added to the Android folder. Once you have more issues, post a new question.

Comment: Rather than USB or Bluetooth could you use wifi?  So create a hotspot on the phone and the other embedded device connect to the phone's wifi hotspot, then communication via sockets?

Comment: @OutsideCoder I think that WiFi can be a better solution than GoNative :)

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Is my comment your preferred solution?  I'm considering this solution to answer my own question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/58302056/6120066).